# How to do a loop for plotting data and exporting it in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with a lot of data and I tried plotting it with this : (getting one plot for each specie and each country given a date-range)

```
> ggplot(my_data, aes(x = Date, y = median, group = Specie, color = Specie)) +
+     geom_line() +
+     geom_point() +
+     facet_wrap(vars(Country))
```

but the result is illegible because I have over 100 countries

How can I loop and export each plot for each country ?

Here are the first lines of the dataframe :

```
    Date   Country Specie median
1   2014-12-29  AT  co    0.1
2   2014-12-29  AT  no2   15.780000000000001
3   2014-12-29  AT  pm10  20.8
4   2014-12-29  AT  pm25  69.5
5   2014-12-29  AT  so2   2.0
6   2014-12-29  AU  co    2.3333333333333335
7   2014-12-29  AU  neph  6.333333333333333
8   2014-12-29  AU  no2   4.314285714285714
9   2014-12-29  AU  o3     13.171428571428569
10  2014-12-29  AU  pm10    11.666666666666666
11  2014-12-29  AU  pm25    18.22222222222222
12  2014-12-29  AU  so2     3.3166666666666664
13  2014-12-29  BE  co     0.1
14  2014-12-29  BE  no2    19.416666666666668
15  2014-12-29  BE  o3  5.666666666666667
```

Comment: Check out the link. This is a good example for your task. https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first split the data.frame into a list, where each list element is a data.frame with just one of the countries.

```
df$ID <- paste(df$Country, df$Specie, sep = "_")
df_list <- split(df, df$ID)
```

You can then iterate over the list and make your plots.

```
lapply(names(df_list), function(x) {
  p <- ggplot(df_list[[x]], aes(x = Date, y = median, group = Specie, color = Specie)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
  ggsave(paste0(x, "_plot.png"), plot = p)
})
```

Comment: I got the error `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class Date

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the error. I forgot to propegate the new variable, 'df_list', to the the lapply function.

Comment: It did work thank you! however, the species are all in the same plot, is there a way to separate the plots for each `Specie` please? it would be a great help

Comment: I edited the answer. I first just made a new column with the two variables concatenated into one string, and then split by that new column.

Comment: Thank you very much <3

Answer (score 0):

```
library("readxl")
library(ggplot2)
my_data <- read_excel("lab.xlsx")

library(ggplot2)
pdf("all_plots_file.pdf",onefile = TRUE)
country_list <- as.list(unique(my_data$Country))
for(country in country_list){

    data <- subset(my_data, my_data$Country==country)
    p<- ggplot(data, aes(x=as.Date(Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y"), median, group = 1, color = Specie)) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_point() +
        xlab("Date") + 
        ylab("Median") + 
        labs(title = country) +
        theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue", size=10)) +
        theme(axis.title.y = element_text(colour="blue", size=10)) +
        scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m/%d/%Y")


    plot(p)
}
dev.off()
```